# Advanced DataGrid in flex

Tags: advanceddatagrid

I am using AdvancedDataGrid with its number of rows changing dynamically.I want to adjust the grid height according to the number of rows displayed.Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking... please provide an example. You want the grid to keep getting taller as the row number increases? Is this to avoid a scroll bar? How tall would you like it to get before you stop? Are you looking for it to be 1:1 (height = numberOfRows * heightOfOneRow)?

It sounds like what you're asking for should be pretty straight forward, if you just elaborate a little bit.

Comment: I want the grid to keep getting taller as the row number increases,so that the grid is kept in tact.I want the scroll bars to appear once the grid's height exceeds the page size.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dupe of [flex datagrid - making grid height dynamic and component that contains it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878683/flex-datagrid-making-grid-height-dynamic-and-component-that-contains-it), and I answer the question more fully over there. Short version: the `rowCount` property controls the height of the DataGrid control.